# XCode Analyzer Warning "result of calloc is converted..."

Tags: c

I have this lines:

```
char* data = (char *) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
...
size_t lineLength = strlen(data);
char *out = calloc(lineLength, sizeof(data));
```

at the last line I get with the new XCode the following warning

```
Result of 'calloc' is converted to a pointer of type 'char', which is incompatible with sizeof operand type 'char *'
```

I stuck a bit is this a real complain?

Comment: There's no point in casting the return value of `mmap()`, in C. It's very much like [`malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169): since it returns `void *` there's no need to cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to correct calloc() statement:

either:

```
char *out = calloc(lineLength, sizeof(*data));
```

(*I think you need this as I can understand that you are allocating for string*)

or

```
char **out = calloc(lineLength, sizeof(data));
```

depends on your need.

Additional point is allocate extra memory for NULL `\0` symbol to terminate string. e.g. for fist case:

```
 char *out = calloc(lineLength + 1, sizeof(*data));
```

Comment: @Sebastian Because allocating more space than needed is not "harmful", it doesn't cause undefined behavior, it's just conceptually wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `sizeof(data*)` <-- what's that?

Answer (score 4):

Yap, it is real. And it hasn't even discovered the entire problem.

When one dynamically allocates memory using the `malloc()` family of functions, which `calloc()` is the member of, for one element, the code often goes like so:

```
T *ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
```

That's fine as long as you don't change the type of the pointer. When you do, you **will** forget to change the type in the `sizeof()`, and possibly you end up allocating less memory than your `T` type takes up, effectively making your program invoke undefined behavior.

***And you just run into this issue.*** (Alhough, technically, here you allocate more memory than needed, no UB, but conceptually it's still wrong.)

```
char *out = calloc(lineLength, sizeof(data));
```

should really be

```
char *out = calloc(lineLength + 1, sizeof(*data));
```

instead. You want to allocate space for `lineLength + 1` pieces of `char`, whereas `data` is a pointer-to-char.

Oh, and ***[do not cast the return value of `mmap()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)***